# Convert recursive __setitem__ to iterative in python

Tags: python, recursion, iteration, binary-search-tree

Here I have the **setitem** method of my Binary Search Tree. I am currently getting the "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded" error so I would like to convert it to an iterative method but I'm kinda stuck. Any hints?

```
class BinarySearchTreeNode:

    def __init__(self, key, item=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.key = key
        self.item = item
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class BinarySearchTree:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        self.root = self._setitem_aux_(self.root, key, item)

    # here convert this to an iterative method
    def _setitem_aux_(self, current, key, item):
        if current is None:
            current = BinarySearchTreeNode(key, item)
        elif key < current.key:
            current.left = self._setitem_aux_(current.left, key, item)
        elif key > current.key:
            current.right = self._setitem_aux_(current.right, key, item)
        else: # key == current.key
            current.item = item
        return current
```

And call it:

```
bst = BinarySearchTree() 
# To set an item with key = 0, item = 1
bst[0] = 1 
# To set an item with key = "abcd", item = 10
bst["abcd"] = 10
```

Comment: Can you add how you call this class ?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh
bst = BinarySearchTree()
ex: To set an item with key = 0, item = 1:
bst[0] = 1
To set an item with key = "abcd", item = 10:
bst[ "abcd"] = 10

Comment: you need to add the condition when you reach at the leaf node ie left or right is None then return

Comment: add to the question please not the comment

Comment: since you are iterating and want to go to matched node, then you need to check then node , that is you are doing then you need to check the leaft node, if reach at leaf node then what to do, so in that case check the node, ie curren=self.node , if curren.left : then check that node else if current.left is none return current node, also you need to set the variable which is keeping check of the current node where you are working now. see @valentinb solution

Comment: If you are iterating, use an array (list) to store your tree, and manipulate the index.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this ?

```
def __setitem__(self, key, item):
    if self.root is None:
        self.root = BinarySearchTreeNode(key, item)
    else:
        current = self.root
        found = False
        max_iter = 10000  # set this to the appropriate value for your use case
        iter_ = 1
        while not found and iter < max_iter:
            if current is None:
                raise IndexError("Index out of bounds")
            elif key < current.key:
                current = current.left
            elif key > current.key:
                current = current.right
            else:
                found = True
            iter_ += 1

        if found:
            self.root = current
        else:
            raise IndexError("Index too far from root")
```

NB: Recursion is a powerful yet dangerous pattern. It can also hinder code readability. It should be avoided when an iterative piece of code can achieve the same result.